# Left hand side of a generalized zip function never typechecks

Tags: idris, typechecking

I am trying to write a zip function in Idris that combines arbitrarily many vectors of the same length (`len`) into a single vector of `HList`s.

That is, I am trying to generalize the following function:

```
module Zip

import Data.Vect

%default total

zip2 : (Vect len a, Vect len b) -> Vect len (a, b)
zip2 ([], []) = []
zip2 ((x :: xs), (y :: ys)) = (x, y) :: zip2 (xs, ys)
```

I define my own `HList` ("heterogenous list") using vectors:

```
data HList : Vect n Type -> Type  where
  Nil : HList []
  (::) : (x : a) -> (xs : HList as) -> HList (a :: as)
```

Here is a variant of the `zip2` function using this `HList`:

```
zip2H : HList [Vect len a, Vect len b] -> Vect len (HList [a, b])
zip2H [[], []] = []
zip2H [(x :: xs), (y :: ys)] = [x, y] :: zip2H [xs, ys]
```

So far, so good.

Now the general case.

The type signature for arbitrarily many vectors to zip gets a fair bit more complicated, but I am confident that I got it right.

`n` is the number of vectors to zip. `len` is the length of each of these vectors:

```
vects : (len : Nat) -> Vect n Type -> Vect n Type
vects len as = map (\type => Vect len type) as
-- Example:
-- `vects len [a, b] = [Vect len a, Vect len b]`
-- You cannot pattern-match on types in Idris, so you cannot get an `a` from an `Vect len a`. Instead, I go the other way around in `zip` and pass my `a`s implicitly.

zip : {types : Vect (S n) Type} -> {len : Nat} -> HList (vects len types) -> Vect len (HList types)
```

Now my problem is: I cannot write even the left hand side of the definition of `zip`. The type checker keeps complaining.

An example:

```
zip {n = Z} [xs] = ?zip_rhs1
zip xs = ?zip_rhs2
```

```
When checking left hand side of Zip.zip:
When checking an application of Zip.zip:
        Type mismatch between
                HList [a] (Type of [xs])
        and
                HList (Data.Vect.Vect n implementation of Prelude.Functor.Functor, method map (\type =>
                                                                                                 Vect len
                                                                                                      type)
                                                                                              types) (Expected type)

        Specifically:
                Type mismatch between
                        [a]
                and
                        Data.Vect.Vect n implementation of Prelude.Functor.Functor, method map (\type =>
                                                                                                  Vect len
                                                                                                       type)
                                                                                               types
```

What am I missing? Am I using the implicit parameters in a wrong manner? Do I need to write some proofs? Is there a better way to structure the function type signature?

(My Idris version is `1.3.1-git:a93d8c9`.)

**EDIT:** Using HTNW's code I still get basically the same error:

```
module Zip

import Data.Vect

%default total

data HList : Vect n Type -> Type  where
  Nil : HList []
  (::) : (x : a) -> (xs : HList as) -> HList (a :: as)

vects : (len : Nat) -> Vect n Type -> Vect n Type
vects len as = map (\type => Vect len type) as

multiUnCons : {len : Nat} -> {types : Vect n Type} ->
              HList (vects (S len) types) -> (HList types, HList (vects len types))
multiUnCons {types = []} [] = ([], [])
multiUnCons {types = t :: ts} ((x :: xs) :: xss) with (multiUnCons xss)
  | (ys, yss) = (x :: ys, xs :: yss)

zip : {types : Vect n Type} -> {len : Nat} ->
      HList (vects len types) -> Vect len (HList types)
zip {len = Z} _ = []
zip {len = S n} xss with (multiUnCons xss)
  | (ys, yss) = ys :: zip yss

testVectors : HList [Vect 3 Nat, Vect 3 Char]
testVectors = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

```
*zip> :t Zip.zip testVectors
(input):1:4-23:When checking an application of function Zip.zip:
        Type mismatch between
                HList [Vect 3 Nat, Vect 3 Char] (Type of testVectors)
        and
                HList (vects len types) (Expected type)

        Specifically:
                Type mismatch between
                        [Vect 3 Nat, Vect 3 Char]
                and
                        Data.Vect.Vect n implementation of Prelude.Functor.Functor, method map (\type =>
                                                                                                  Vect len
                                                                                                       type)
                                                                                               types
```

**RESOLUTION:** `zip` needs more information:

```
*zip> the (Vect 3 (HList [Nat, Char])) (zip testVectors)
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c']] : Vect 3 (HList [Nat, Char])
```

```
*zip> zip {types=[Nat, Char]} testVectors
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c']] : Vect 3 (HList [Nat, Char])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to match on `types`, too. By matching on `types`, you also reveal something about `vects len types`, and this is what allows you to further match on the `HList (vects len types)` argument. Also, the `S n` length requirement on `types` is unnecessary and broken. Finally, I think you actually need to recurse on `len` first, then on `types`. The recursion on `types` is best written as a different function:

```
multiUnCons : {len : Nat} -> {types : Vect n Type} ->
              HList (vects (S len) types) -> (HList types, HList (vects len types))
multiUnCons {types = []} [] = ([], [])
multiUnCons {types = t :: ts} ((x :: xs) :: xss) with (multiUnCons xss)
  | (ys, yss) = (x :: ys, xs :: yss)
```

And `zip` itself is pretty simple:

```
zip : {types : Vect n Type} -> {len : Nat} ->
      HList (vects len types) -> Vect len (HList types)
zip {len = Z} _ = []
zip {len = S n} xss with (multiUnCons xss)
  | (ys, yss) = ys :: zip yss
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The code looks convincing. However, when I paste it to the rest of the code and call e.g. `Zip.zip testVectors`, where I define `testVectors` as 
`testVectors : HList [Vect 3 Nat, Vect 3 Char]`
`testVectors = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']]`
I still get basically the same error.
(I will edit the question to include the new error message.)

Comment: @Dufaer That would most likely be because, as we have both said, Idris cannot work backwards for types. `zip` wants a `HList (vects len types)`, you give it a `HList [Vect 3 Nat, Vect 3 Char]`. As humans, we deduce `types = [Nat, Char]; len = 3`. Idris does not. A type ascription works: `the (Vect 3 (HList [Nat, Char])) (zip testVectors)`, and so does `zip {types=[Nat, Char]} testVector`.

Comment: Wow. Indeed it does. Never thought about the implications of that. Thank you!

Comment: This need to specify specify the output (or pass in an implicit parameter) seems to make the whole function significantly less useful. I would rather use a family of zip functions (`zip2`, ... , `zip22`, say), because then I have to specify less when I call them. Maybe it pays dividends, when composed into larger polymorphic function, though?